# Alignment of table header in column with decimal numbers using siunitx

Tags: tables, siunitx

I have a table with decimal numbers aligned at decimal point. In the column header, I have a % sign. In the code snippet given below, the percent sign is aligned at the left in the column, but I would like it to be either aligning with the decimal points or to the right. How can I achieve this?

Current result:

[image]

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l S[table-format=3.2]}
    \textbf{fruit} & \textbf{\%} \\
    apple   & 12,34 \\
    banana  & ,1 \\
    cherry  & 1,2345 \\
    coconut & 100 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can align to the right by using `multicolumn`:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l S[table-format=3.4]}
    \textbf{fruit} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{\%}} \\         %  
    apple   & 12,34 \\
    banana  & ,1 \\
    cherry  & 1,2345 \\
    coconut & 100 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I have changed `S[table-format=3.2]` to `S[table-format=3.4]` so as to compensate for the entry in cherry..

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To center the `%` symbol in the header row of the second column, you could encase the instruction `\textbf{\%}` in curly braces, like this:

```
{\textbf{\%}}
```

Using `\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\%}}` works too...

Comment: This would only center the symbol over the whole column width, but not aligning it at the decimal point.

Comment: @Martin - In the present case, i.e., given the OP's data for the various percentages, centering the `%` symbols works out to being pretty much the same as aligning it directly on the decimal point. :-)